# How can I find out who is notified when my Teams status changes?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I saw that in MS Teams we do [have to possibility to be notified when someone becomes available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-notified-when-someone-s-status-changes-in-teams-7363ccdb-40d2-4628-b03d-c8f515830933).

Is there a way to know who is notified when *I* become available? I.e. who has added me to their status change notification list?
I am suspecting some on my entourage are using this functionality to spot who's behind their laptop and who is doing long coffee breaks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean  by "subscribed to you" in the context of Teams?  You can friend somebody on Teams, are join a Team which has members, but I have never heard of subscribing to an specific user.

Comment: Have you done some [research](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on what the possibilities are?

Comment: @Ramhound you can be notified whenever [a person becomes available in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-notified-when-someone-s-status-changes-in-teams-7363ccdb-40d2-4628-b03d-c8f515830933). The question asker wants to know who of his colleagues is being notified whenever the question asker changes status.

Comment: The author should refer to it as adding a user to the status change notification list instead a subscription to user in that case.

Comment: As this is SE I've taken the freedom to edit the question (as anyone could). I hope I got the gist of it right.

Answer (score 6):

If you are concerned that someone might monitor you through your status changes, you can set your [status manually for a certain duration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-duration-for-your-status-in-teams-d82c5629-96a8-44e9-bced-2925470e0d96). It will then not change based on your activity, your calendar, and the state of your computer (for the set duration).

Note that this only covers the monitoring through the Teams status. Other possible monitoring methods are not avoided.

Comment: Indeed that's what I did but I wanted to know the names to collect real proofs of the behavior. As the monitoring behavior is not declared in my contract, it's a violation of our rights

Comment: I'll not validate your answer as it's more a workaround than an answer right ?

Comment: It's up to you to decide if you want to accept it. The SE network is about solving problems. Your problem seemed to be that you don't want to be tracked by your teams status, my answer solves that problem. If you want to stop tracking because you feel its a contract breach it's a different problem. Perhaps [workplace.se] can help.

Comment: My problem is how can I see who's notified, because I do want to know the 'who' :-) 
I already knew how to avoid the behavior of notify the others

Comment: And why do you want to know the "who"? Also see the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/222653).

Comment: Because in belgium it's illegal to monitor employee without notifying them ;-)

Comment: it's not a XY problem, since the begin I asked for who because I want to know who and not how to avoid it... as I said I already knew how to avoid it

Comment: I would argue *it is* an XY problem. You didn't simply wake up and think: "How do I know who is notified of my presence in Teams?" (Y), you have some underlying problem (X) you want to deal with. Perhaps you want to stop others from doing this because it's illegal (see [law.se]), perhaps you want to change office culture (see [workplace.se]), or perhaps you feel this monitoring harms your [interpersonal.se] relations at work? I don't know, as it's not included in your question.

Comment: No I just want to know who ...

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I'm tired with people always refering to XY problem. The guy asked if there is a way to know the people who are tracking his status. The question is simple, clear, and articulable...

Comment: The XY problem is not about the original question being complicated or not articulabe, as the [examples also show](https://xyproblem.info/). It's that a question is being asked with a certain goal in mind, without disclosing what that goal is. In the end the SE network is about solving problems and not just answering questions, therefore it's worthwile to spend some time on investigating what the underling issue is that the asker is trying to solve (X), instead of only focussing on the sought after solution (Y).

Comment: Though you are perfectly welcome to answer *Y* if you can...

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Good answer. Sadly, "Available" is the only status you can't set a duration for in the current version of Teams, but reading the linked article I get the impression that they could all have durations set at one point.